# Could not join Multicast group : No such Device

Tags: udp, gstreamer, multicast, v4l2

I would like to stream camera data over UDP multicast using gstreamer.

For that i used below pipeline,

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=720,height=576,framerate=25/1 ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=9090 auto-multicast=true sync=true async=false qos=true
```

But, I am getting below error,

```
could not get/set settings from/on resource : gstmultiudpsink.c(948): gst_multiudpsink_configure_client (): 
Could not join Multicast group : No such Device
```

But, the same pipeline is working in Ubuntu14.10 64 bit PC.

It didn't work on RHEL7 64 bit PC.

These both pc's are connected to same switch.

What is the problem here? and how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188060/3387027) answer helped me with a similar problem.

I configured a route for a multicast traffic with command

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 224.0.0.0 enp0s3
```

where `enp0s3` is my network interface's name.