# Connect a RTP stream to Kurento Media Server and broadacast using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, rtp, kurento

I am trying to create a WebRtc stream using `Kurento` Media Server and a hardware video encoder.

The video source is coming from `Haivision Makito DVI`. `Makito` is a hardware encoder which captures a FHD display using DVI cable, compresses using h.264 codec and streams in number of protocols options (`TS over UDP`, `TS over RTP`, `Direct RTP`, `Quicktime`, `RTMP`).

- So far I have managed to play a RTSP stream from `vlc` to `Kurento`
  I have implemented a RtpEndpoint -> WebRtc example which is published in this [repository](https://github.com/givo/kurento-rtpendpoint). (This proves `Kurento` works)
- The encoder's `sdp` can be accessed here - [SDP](https://github.com/givo/kurento-rtpendpoint/blob/rtpendpoint/Kurento/stream.sdp).
- At first `Kurento` had crashed and throw an error saying "Could not join Multicast group: No such Device" which I solved using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998344/could-not-join-multicast-group-no-such-device).
- Now, my server side and client side are working and communicating perfectly but no video can be seen.
  **Currently I don't have a clue what is the problem.**
- This is the SDP answer generated by Kurento after using `rtpEndpoint.processOffer()`:

`

```
v = 0
o =- 3718280759 3718280759 IN IP4 192.168.6.20
s = Kurento Media Server
c = IN IP4 192.168.6.20
t = 0 0
m = video 58116 RTP/AVP 96
a = fmtp: 96 packetisation-mode=1; sprop=parameter-sets=Z0IAKYxoB4ifl/8AAQABEAAAAMAQAAADyEAAAAAAA=,aM48gAAAAA=
a = ssrc:3106833799 cname:user3165393302@host-52028916
m = audio 34338 RTP/AVP
a = ssrc:396556932 cname:user3165393302@host-52028916
```

- Which of the above protocols does Kurento currently support?
- Do I place some commands in the wrong order?
- What am I doing wrong?

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `Makito` transmits video to a predefined fixed udp port.

To solved it I am extracting the udp port from the sdp answer generated by `Kurento` and configuring `Makito`'s destination udp port at runtime using a simple script.

Comment: can  you please share UDP settings?

Comment: You can take a look at the readme file inside my [repo](https://github.com/givo/kurento-rtpendpoint)